# I am not able get the sorted values from the input

Tags: python

problem with sorting

```
a = raw_input("Do you know the number of inputs ?(y/n)")    
if a == 'y':    
   n = int(input("Enter the number of inputs : "))    
   total = 0    
   i = 1    
  while i <= n:     
   s = input()    
   total = total + int(s)    
   i = i + 1    
   s.sort()    
   print s     
   print('The sum is ' + str(total))
```

Comment: Please Properly intent your code. !

Comment: Please properly case your sentence! @RahulKP, on a serious note, you could edit his post and help him out, instead of posting meaningless comments.

Comment: Can show me how to sort the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to `sort` on input. `sort` only work on iterating like list and tuples.

I just rewrite your code,

```
a = raw_input("Do you know the number of inputs ?(y/n)")
if a == 'y':
    n = int(input("Enter the number of inputs : "))
    inputs = [] 
    for i in range(n):
        s = input()
        inputs.append(int(s))
    inputs.sort()

    print inputs 
    print('The sum is ',sum(inputs))
```

***Edit***

Just change whole operation into a function and put yes/no question in a while loop, And for wrong entry exit from program.

```
def foo():
    n = int(input("Enter the number of inputs : "))
    inputs = [] 
    for i in range(n):
        s = input()
        inputs.append(int(s))
    inputs.sort()

    print inputs 
    print('The sum is ',sum(inputs))

while True:
    a = raw_input("Do you know the number of inputs ?(y/n)")    
    if a == 'y':
        foo()       
    elif a == 'n':
        print 'We are giving one more option.'      
        continue
    else:
        print 'Wrong entry'
        break
```

Comment: how to repeat the same procedure in "a == y" in "a == n"

Comment: Please ask as separate question beacuse it's out of context.You just this link reference https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: I am not able to ask another question. the stackoverflow is showing that you have exceeded the limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of inputs : "))
total = 0
i = 1
array = []
while i <= n:
    s = int(input())
    array.append(s)
    total = total + int(s)
    i = i + 1
array.sort()
print(array) 
print('The sum is ' + str(total))
```

this will solve your problem, sort applies on list not on str object

Answer (score 0):

Store the numbers in a list. Then use sum(list) to get the sum of elements in the list, and sorted(list) to get the list sorted in ascending order.

```
    n = int(input("Enter the number of inputs: "))

    l=[]

    for i in range(n):

        s = input()

        l.append(int(s))

    print('The sum is', sum(l))

    print('Sorted values', sorted(l))
```

Were you looking for this?

Comment: Do: sorted(l)[::-1]

Comment: if i write : reverse(l)

Comment: It's either l.reverse() or reversed(l). And pls do hit the up vote button if you like my answer :)